# finding $f'(0)$ from $|f(x)| \le 2|x|^3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Given that
$$|f(x)| \le 2|x|^3  $$
How can I show that $f'(0) = 0$ exists?

I know that since modulus function cannot be negative, therefore,
$$0 \le |f(0)| \le 2|x|^3=0$$
$$f'(0)= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
$$-\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\le \frac{f(x)}{x}\le\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}$$
and as $x$ goes to $0$ by squeeze theorem,
$$f'(0)= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$

is this correct?

Comment: It's correct, but you don't need to get rid of the absolute value because $h(x) \to 0 \iff |h(x)| \to 0$ for any function $h$. And, for the sake of clarity I would add the line $|f(x)/x| \le 2|x|^2 \to 0$

Answer (score 3):

You write

$$\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\leq \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

however, this is false. The right side can be negative while the left side is always positive. Rather use that
$$0 \leq \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \leq 2|x|^2$$

and thus by squeeze theorem, we see that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ |f(x)|}{|x|}=0$ or equivently $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I guess the incorrect inequality you pointed out could be corrected by simply putting a minus sign in the left hand side. Then it would be $-2|x|^{2} \le -\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \le \frac{f(x)}{x}$. But this is just another approach.

Comment: Yup. I forgot about the minus sign. Have since edited it.

Comment: Yes, then it is correct!